# "Ciphering services not available" error with SNMP V3 usage of pysnmp in python v3 virtual environment

Tags: snmp, pycrypto, pysnmp, pycryptodome

I am trying to use pysnmp library with SNMP V3 settings with MD5 Auth protocol and AesCfb128 Priv protocol to obtain details from a switch. I am trying two things.

*1. Install pysnmp and all dependency packages (including pycrytpto) in base machine*

*2. Create virtual environment for python3 and install pysnmp and all dependency packages (including pycrytpto) in this virtual environment.*

When I take the 1st approach, details are retrieved properly. But when I try the 2nd approach, I am getting "Ciphering services not available" error. I checked that list of installed packages are pretty much same across the both.

**Here are the details of base machine**

```
$ pip3 list

pip (9.0.1)

ply (3.11)

pyasn1 (0.4.5)

pycryptodomex (3.8.2)

pysmi (0.3.4)

pysnmp (4.4.9)

setuptools (28.8.0)
```

**My Virtual Environment is created in location "/Users//Test/Python/Pysnmp"**

```
$ /Users/<user_name>/Test/Python/Pysnmp/bin/pip3 list

Package Version

pip 18.1

pipdeptree 0.13.2

ply 3.11

pyasn1 0.4.5

pycryptodomex 3.8.2

pysmi 0.3.4

pysnmp 4.4.9

setuptools 40.6.2
```

Here is the command that I am trying to use

```
for (errorIndication,errorStatus,errorIndex,varBinds) in nextCmd(SnmpEngine(),
    UsmUserData('test_user', 'test_password', 'test_password', usmHMACMD5AuthProtocol, usmAesCfb128Protocol),
    UdpTransportTarget((host, 161)), ContextData(),
    ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(oid)), lexicographicMode=False):
```

When I run above code in base machine (like `python3 script.py`), it returns the details properly.

But when I run it using the python installed inside virtual environment (like `/Users/<user_name>/Test/Python/Pysnmp/bin/python3 script.py`), it returns "**Ciphering services not available**" as errorindication.

What am I missing???

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure whether this is the good place to ask this question or whether I should ask it on github. So I posted this on github also @ https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp/issues/285

Comment: I hope this is now [resolved](https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp/issues/285)

Comment: Yes. As discussed on the github, we are fine with this now.