# pysnmp: For SNMP V3 trap decryption, getting error: "Ciphering services not available or ciphertext is broken"

Tags: python, encryption, snmp, pysnmp, snmp-trap

Trap messages are received and decoded properly, when collected using tcpdump and viewed in wireshark.

But with pysnmp lib, getting the below error:

2023-04-11 11:55:54,792 pysnmp: processIncomingMsg: scopedPDU decoder failed <class 'pyasn1.error.SubstrateUnderrunError'>
2023-04-11 11:55:54,792 pysnmp: StatusInformation: {'errorIndication': DecryptionError('Ciphering services not available or ciphertext is broken'), 'msgUserName': <OctetString value object, tagSet <TagSet object, tags 0:0:4>, subtypeSpec <ConstraintsIntersection object, consts <ValueSizeConstraint object, consts 0, 32>>, encoding iso-8859-1, payload [user1]>}
2023-04-11 11:55:54,792 pysnmp: prepareDataElements: SM failed, statusInformation {'errorIndication': DecryptionError('Ciphering services not available or ciphertext is broken'), 'msgUserName': <OctetString value object, tagSet <TagSet object, tags 0:0:4>, subtypeSpec <ConstraintsIntersection object, consts <ValueSizeConstraint object, consts 0, 32>>, encoding iso-8859-1, payload [user1]>}

Package                        Version

---

bcrypt                         3.2.0
certifi                        2022.12.7
cffi                           1.14.4
cryptography                   38.0.1
netmiko                        3.2.0
paramiko                       2.7.2
pip                            23.0.1
ply                            3.11
pyasn1                         0.4.8
pycparser                      2.20
pycrypto                       2.6.1
pycryptodomex                  3.15.0
pylzma                         0.5.0
PyNaCl                         1.4.0
pyOpenSSL                      22.1.0
pyserial                       3.5
pysmi                          0.3.4
pysnmp                         4.4.12
PySocks                        1.7.1
python-dateutil                2.8.1
pytz                           2020.4
pyvmomi                        8.0.0.1.2
PyYAML                         5.3.1

I tried the solution provided in all the below links, still the issue is not resulved:

1. ["Ciphering services not available" error with SNMP V3 usage of pysnmp in python v3 virtual environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57116952/ciphering-services-not-available-error-with-snmp-v3-usage-of-pysnmp-in-python)
2. https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp/issues/285   (python -c 'from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES')
3. https://sourceforge.net/p/pysnmp/discussion/46667/thread/623edabb/ (pycrypto was not there I installed and tried)

Answer (score 0):

SNMP v3 TRAP is a rather lengthy ceremony that

- You need to set the proper engine ID when sending it out, like [this](https://github.com/lextudio/pysnmp/blob/main/tests/hlapi/asyncio/agent/ntforg/test_v3-trap.py#L12)

```py
        snmpEngine = SnmpEngine(OctetString(hexValue="8000000001020304"))
        errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = await sendNotification(
            snmpEngine,
            UsmUserData("usr-md5-des", "authkey1", "privkey1"),
            UdpTransportTarget(("localhost", MANAGER_PORT)),
            ContextData(),
            "trap",
            NotificationType(ObjectIdentity("IF-MIB", "linkDown")),
        )

        snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.closeDispatcher()
```

- You also need to register the same engine ID with the user, like [this](https://github.com/lextudio/pysnmp/blob/main/tests/manager_context.py#L54)

```py
    # user: usr-md5-des, auth: MD5, priv DES, securityEngineId: 8000000001020304
    # this USM entry is used for TRAP receiving purposes
    config.addV3User(
        snmpEngine,
        "usr-md5-des",
        config.usmHMACMD5AuthProtocol,
        "authkey1",
        config.usmDESPrivProtocol,
        "privkey1",
        securityEngineId=v2c.OctetString(hexValue="8000000001020304"),
    )
```

It simply won't work if you miss either.